# Wildfly - Bind a data source in runtime

Tags: wildfly

In AS6/7, I was able to bind a Data Source object in runtime like this -

```
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    NonSerializableFactory.rebind(ctx, jndiName, ds);
```

But NonSerializableFactory class is no more available in wild-fly and there is no way to bind non-serializable object in ctx in runtime. I could not find any replacement of NonSerializableFactory. 
Instead I tried the following -
ctx.rebind(jndiName, ds)
But the above is not working. I don't see datasource bound and I am not able to access it. Will greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: this was the same in AS7, but versions before ware too forgiving where jndi was writable. To what jndi namespace are you trying to bind datasource?